# What's wrong with my beautiful form (HAML, Rails, Formtastique, Mongoid)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, haml, formtastic

(I have no collage model, could that be the problem?)

I'm trying to create a form in HAML, Rails, and Mongoid and I can't get the naming of each field right.

Collage is a group of 15 Works, Works have a column called "slide_number" that is either the slide number if they're in the collage or nil if they aren't.

This is the line (in _form.html.haml) that's giving me trouble:

```
 = f.input "slide_"+(index+1).to_s, :collection => Work.all.map{|w| [w.name, w._id]}
```

If I do the following line the form is rendered, but all dropdowns are labelled "One" and when I submit the form I only get info from the last form (because everything is named the same).

```
= f.input :one, :collection => Work.all.map{|w| [w.name, w._id]}
```

collage_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @collage = Work.excludes(:slide_number => nil).order_by([:slide_number, :asc])
    @work = Work.all.order_by([:slide_number, :asc])
    slides = Array.new
    15.times do |index|
      if Work.where(:slide_number => index+1).first
        slides << Work.where(:slide_number => index+1).first.id
      else
        slides << nil
      end
      @slides= slides
    end
end
```

_form.html.haml

```
= semantic_form_for :collage do |f| 
    - @slides.each_with_index do |slide, index|
        = f.input "slide_"+(index+1).to_s, :collection => Work.all.map{|w| [w.name, w._id]}
    .actions
        = f.commit_button
```

This is the error I get:

```
NoMethodError in Collage#edit

Showing /Users/nickgoddard/codebase/subrosa/app/views/collage/_form.html.haml where line #7 raised:

undefined method `slide_1' for []:Array
```

Any help much appreciated.  I don't really understand what the first attribute after f.input is or is supposed to do.

Comment: If you want to make the form based upon a collage it would be easier to have a collage model.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a form that way without a model, but this should get you past that.

[Is there any way to create a form with formtastic without a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991468/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-form-with-formtastic-without-a-model)